# How to use setNativeProps() on react-native ART objects?

Tags: react-native, graphics

I would like to use `setNativeProps()` on a `<Surface>` like this:

```
render = () => (
  <Surface
    ref = {ref => this.surfaceRef = ref}
  />
)

moveSurface (x,y) => {
  this.surfaceRef.setNativeProps({
    transform: {[translateX: x}, {translateY: y}]
  })
}
```

This doesn't work since none of the ART components seems to implement setNativeProps. I thought that at least `Surface` would implement this function since it extends `Component`.

Background:
I do this (similar) with react-native-svg with success. But I need more fps. ART is a little more performant than react-native-svg so I'd like to see how ART performs with setNativeProps and compare it to react-native-svg.